# Way to minimize scripts start-up time via persistence?

Tags: performance, time, startup, fastcgi, raku

`Raku` start-up times are notoriously *huge*.

---

On my machine (old one but the most modern I own):

`time raku -e 'put "Hello, World!"'`
495.67 - 567.02 millis
(1.53 secs for the 1st time launch)

`time perl -E 'say "Hello, World!"'`
13.63 - 19.51 millis

`time sh -c 'echo "Hello, World!"'`
4.31 - 6.88 millis

`c`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    puts("Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

`time ./hello`
5.03 - 7.67 millis
`time clang hello.c -o hello` (compile)
126.39 - 195.66 millis

---

`Raku` does boast many nifties built-in which make it heavy.
Yet sometimes you need a rather simple script, and you would prefer `Raku` for its elegance, but launch-time spent waiting brings dissatisfaction and you don't pick `Raku` for your next simple script.

Is there a way to help it?
Like starting `Raku` once and keeping it running, and making it handle all `Raku` scripts, with and without modules, big and small, and `raku -e ...` as well?
Something like `FastCGI` but for local shell?

---

Even sacrificing permanently *huge* amount of memory is better for me than wasting time waiting.
In KiloBytes, according to `ps`:

```
                                      Virtual size  Resident set size

raku -e 'loop {sleep 1}'                    146704  107200

perl -e 'while (1) {sleep 1}'                 1252    4036

sh -c 'while true; do sleep 1; done'           892     900

#include <unistd.h>
void main(void) { for(;;) {sleep(1);} }        172     780
```

---

## Update:

Elaborating upon
`raku -e 'while prompt "Enter filename: " -> $filename { EVALFILE $filename }'`
from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73873471/14812514

Concocted from https://docs.raku.org/type/IO::Socket::INET and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/perl/perl_socket_programming.htm

`raku-persistent`, heavy server:

```
#! /usr/bin/env raku

use MONKEY-SEE-NO-EVAL;

my $listen = IO::Socket::INET.new( :listen,
                                   :localhost<localhost>,
                                   :localport(3333) );
loop {
    my $conn = $listen.accept;
    try {
        while my $buf = $conn.recv() {
            put now - (EVAL $buf)[1] - 37;  # also subtract leap seconds
            EVALFILE (EVAL $buf)[0];
        }
    }
    $conn.close;
    CATCH { default {.payload.say} }
}
```

`ra`, light client:

```perl
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Time::HiRes;
use Socket;

my $file = shift || '/tmp/test.raku';
my $arg1 = shift || Time::HiRes::time;

# initialize host and port
my $host = shift || 'localhost';
my $port = shift || 3333;
my $server = "localhost";  # Host IP running the server

# create the socket, connect to the port
socket(SOCKET,PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,(getprotobyname('tcp'))[2])
   or die "Can't create a socket $!\n";
connect(SOCKET, pack_sockaddr_in($port, inet_aton($server)))
   or die "Can't connect to port $port! \n";

printf SOCKET '["%s", %f]', $file, $arg1;
close SOCKET or die "close: $!";
```

`/tmp/test.raku`:

```
put "Hello, World!";
run 'notify-send', 'Hello, World!'
```

`raku-persistent` in one terminal, once;
`ra [script.raku]` in another terminal, how many times you want.

Delay ranges 0.008848472 - 1.322056732; in most cases being below 0.07.
0.008848472 must be some kind of a mistake - it is less than perl startup time, which is impossible.

This is still a proof of concept since arguments don't get into the target script.

---

## Update 2:

As a reaction to https://stackoverflow.com/a/73918912/14812514

Suggested bench [suite](https://github.com/bdrung/startup-time) doesn't work via `Makefile` on my machines, even on Debian-based antiX 21, and possible [solution](https://github.com/bdrung/startup-time/issues/6) was found after I had done all measurements semi-manually. Moreover, on OpenBSD `run.c` [doesn't](https://github.com/bdrung/startup-time/issues/7) even compile. Being zero at `c`, I resorted to shell `time for i in $(seq 1000); do ./<file> >/dev/null; done`.
All 4 machines with HDD, no SSD.
My initial configuration is i5-3320M OpenBSD and marked with `^`.
Results in **seconds** for **1K invocations**, also for **single invocation for Raku only**:

```
 CPU           cores  GHz  OS            via         Raku K     Raku 1    Perl K  C K
 Pentium 4-M i686  1  2.2  OpenBSD i386  shell seq   36m32.479  2.192479  22.368  6.408
 Core 2 Duo T5800  2  2    antiX         c run       10m34.460  0.63446    2.224  0.535
 Core 2 Duo T5800  2  2    antiX         shell seq    7m48.153  0.468153   3.878  1.509
^i5-3320M          2  2.6  OpenBSD       shell seq    8m 0.011  0.480011   8.150  2.258
 i5-3320M          2  2.6  antiX live    c run        4m53.469  0.293469   1.157  0.276
 i5-3320M          2  2.6  antiX live    shell seq    3m37.042  0.217042   1.688  0.615
 i7-3770S          4  3.1  OpenBSD       shell seq    6m44.920  0.40492    7.026  2.340
 i7-3770S          4  3.1  antiX live    c run        4m 5.571  0.245571   0.872  0.268
```

Some highlights:

- Raku startup times are unwelcomely regardless of CPU and OS
- shell `for i in $(seq...` is slower than custom C `run` for Perl & C but outperformed it for Raku - 7m+ vs 10m+ on Core 2 Duo and 3m+ vs 4m+ on i5
- OpenBSD doesn't prioritize speed
- 3rd-party software doesn't prioritize optimization for OpenBSD

Comment: What does `raku -v` say?

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen `2022.06`. After you asked I `rakubrew build moar-master`, Rakudo `2022.07-41-g90709d533` MoarVM `2022.07-9-g740f3bcbe` - same timings of 500+ millis. Older `2021.12` from repo gives 646.90 - 716.58 millis

Comment: Ok, so it's not slow because of an older Rakudo.  I guess also the HDD might be slowing startup down (which would definitely explain the time for the first invocation)

Comment: BTW, looks like a nice module for the ecosystem in the making.

Comment: For `~$ time raku -e 'put "Hello, World!"'` I get for the first invocation:
`Hello, World!`

`real 0m0.260s`
`user 0m0.180s`
`sys 0m0.067s` . This is on a seven-year-old machine (Rakudo v2021.06).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have a recent version of Rakudo, I can say that you have indeed a very slow machine:

```
% time perl -E 'say "Hello, World!"'
Hello, World!
real    0.05s
user    0.00s
sys 0.03s

% time raku -e 'put "Hello, World!"'
Hello, World!
real    0.12s
user    0.12s
sys 0.02s
```

are the numbers I see on a 2-year M1 MacMini.  On a 10+ year old MacMini running Debian, I see:

```
$ time perl -E 'say "Hello, World!"'
Hello, World!

real    0m0.009s
user    0m0.004s
sys 0m0.005s

$ time raku -e 'put "Hello, World!"'
Hello, World!

real    0m0.241s
user    0m0.287s
sys 0m0.041s
```

Now to get back to your question: yes, you can have something like FastCGI but for a local shell:

```
% raku -e 'while prompt "Enter filename: " -> $filename { EVALFILE $filename }
```

run this, enter the name of the script to execute and ENTER, and it will run.  Now, this is the principle: this only runs scripts without arguments. You can build on this allowing for arguments and such.

Comment: OpenBSD 7.1 amd64, ThinkPad T530, 2012 manufacture year, HDD (not SSD), i5-3320M, 16GB RAM - would you assume it should be more performant than 500+ millis?

Comment: At least you provided me with a starting point. TY. Still, might there be some refined, fleshed out solutions? Surely people had the idea of "local FastCGI" earlier. Much earlier, much more clever people than me, with much more need for overcoming performance lag... Not with `Raku` only... None heard of?

Comment: I don't know of any.  Most Raku users nowadays use faster CPUs and SSD's, making it more bearable for scripting I guess.

Answer (score 5):

The client-server model you describes seems like a really good idea to me!  In fact, I've been toying with a similar idea myself; I actually gave a lightning talk on the subject at the 2022 Perl and Raku Conference, [A Nailgun for Raku](https://youtu.be/NT1uBYBubNU).

As that talk mentions, this is the basic idea behind [Nailgun](http://www.martiansoftware.com/nailgun/) – which implements the same idea but for Java.  As you note, it gets a bit more complex than the proof of concept, but definitely seems like a doable Raku project.

On a different note, I agree with Raiph [edit: with Liz, oops!] that the timings you posted are pretty close to a worst-case scenario in terms of launch speed. My go-to reference for language startup time benchmarks is [bdrung/startup-time](https://github.com/bdrung/startup-time), which has both a benchmarking framework and the author's own data.  For comparison, that author clocks a "Hello, World!" C program between 0.26 ms (for a 2018 laptop) and 2.19 ms (for a Raspberry Pi 3).  Those times might provide some context for the 5.03 to 7.67ms time you measured for a "Hello, World!" C programs.