# In a debugged script, is it safe to disable `use strict` and `use warnings`?

Tags: perl

Consider an ideal case where a script has been written with

```perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
```

and thoroughly reviewed, tested and debugged and you are happy with how it works.

There is no dynamically generated code or other fancy stuff in the script, and the code is overall simple and low-tech.

For critical applications, would such a script be as correct and safe with checks commented out:

```perl
# use strict;
# use warnings FATAL => 'all';
```

as it is with them on?

Provided that special caution is taken during edits, upgrades and any other maintenance to re-enable both `use strict` and `use warnings` and re-test.

---

## Edit:

IMHO the correctness in question is worth answering, no matter whether the original reason justifies the hassle in the opinion of the reader. Replies like "you should use it coz you don't loose much" or "you just should coz it's best practice" are non-answers. Let's take a fresh unbiased look at whether `strict` and `warnings` are undoubtedly recommended to be kept on in an already debugged script

---

The reason is <del>performance</del> time to finish task penalties that these pragmas introduce.

## Update

For a script that does its job quickly and is called numerous times and response time is significant, — cumulative effect can make a difference.

## Update: time to finish task penalties

CPU is i5-3320M, OS is OpenBSD 7.2 amd64.

```shell
for i in $(seq 3); do
    time for i in $(seq 10000); do
        /usr/bin/perl -e ';'
    done
    sleep 3
done
sleep 3
for i in $(seq 3); do
    time for i in $(seq 10000); do
        /usr/bin/perl -e 'use strict; use warnings;'
    done
    sleep 3
done
```

perl is v5.32.1, vendor-patched for security (read against performance).
3 passes of 10000 of `/usr/bin/perl -e ';'`:

```plaintext
    1m32.01s real     0m00.60s user     0m03.24s system
    1m32.60s real     0m00.70s user     0m03.42s system
    1m31.53s real     0m00.69s user     0m04.17s system
```

3 passes of 10000 of `/usr/bin/perl -e 'use strict; use warnings;'`:

```plaintext
    2m46.08s real     0m00.72s user     0m04.63s system
    2m48.99s real     0m00.61s user     0m04.79s system
    2m49.64s real     0m00.75s user     0m05.16s system
```

Roughly 75 seconds stopwatch time difference for 10000 invocations.

Same shell command but `perlbrew`-installed `/opt/p5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl` instead of vendor `/usr/bin/perl`:
3 passes of 10000 of `/opt/p5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl -e ';'`:

```plaintext
    1m09.31s real     0m00.48s user     0m02.60s system
    1m12.06s real     0m00.49s user     0m02.94s system
    1m14.81s real     0m00.70s user     0m03.44s system
```

3 passes of 10000 of `/opt/p5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl -e 'use strict; use warnings;'`:

```plaintext
    2m20.81s real     0m00.55s user     0m04.03s system
    2m21.98s real     0m00.72s user     0m04.26s system
    2m21.75s real     0m00.58s user     0m03.86s system
```

Roughly 70 seconds stopwatch time difference for 10000 invocations.

For those who find time taken to be too long, it is due to OpenBSD. I [had done](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73871927/14812514) some measurements, and perl 'hello world' turned out to be 8.150 / 1.688 = 4.8 times slower on OpenBSD than on antiX Linux

## Update 2: `strict`-only time to finish task penalties

`/usr/bin/perl -e 'use strict;'`:

```plaintext
    1m59.70s real     0m00.51s user     0m04.27s system
    1m59.36s real     0m00.58s user     0m04.04s system
    1m57.58s real     0m00.63s user     0m04.50s system
```

Roughly 26 seconds stopwatch time overhead for 10000 invocations.

`/opt/p5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.36.0/bin/perl -e 'use strict;'`:

```plaintext
    1m29.06s real     0m00.59s user     0m04.55s system
    1m30.04s real     0m00.52s user     0m04.57s system
    1m31.26s real     0m00.54s user     0m05.30s system
```

Roughly 20 seconds stopwatch time overhead for 10000 invocations.

## Update 3

Up till now, replies are mostly evasive pointing out negligibility of performance penalties. One may or may not care about 7 milliseconds per invocation or 70 seconds for 10K invocations. Whatever. Please disregard the provided reason or any other possible reason and focus on the actual question about correctness, as it itself deserves a solid answer

Comment: We can never debug all possible execution paths.  What when a file open fails because a user removed the file? How about failed network requests? The program author may not even know that these are happening as a part of some other operation. Etc.  Without warnings you may never know what the program actually does. (Besides, of course, what is the penalty you measured? I'd be very curious to know.)

Comment: I would be very surprised if `use strict; use warnings;` introduce any noticeable performance penalties. Except perhaps if you have a program that produces an excessive amount of warnings. `strict` should be mainly compile time performance.

Comment: "I don't always turn off safety features, but when I do, it's in production."

Comment: 7 ms is a performance penalty? Perhaps you should try that test with some actual code in the program, the percentage penalty should be very small.

Comment: @TLP not 7 ms but **70 seconds**, that is **over a minute**, for 10K invocations, and `strict` alone takes 20 or 26 seconds for 10K invocations

Comment: @uxer 70s/10000 = 7 ms per iteration. If you run that on a program that takes 1 second to execute, the 10k invocations will take almost 3 hours, and the performance penalty of strict and warnings will be 70 seconds of that. That is very small. There are a lot of things you can do with a program to optimize it that are much more effective than that.

Comment: @uxer Thank you -- but you are timing it with compilation, in a program that does nothing.  (Try to load, um say `DateTime` as well, to see how the overall time goes UP.)  While compile time may matter, I don't think that that's what you meant by performance in the question.  Also, there is a bit of randomness when run out of a shell like that.

Comment: @uxer Why not try with a program that takes, say 5-10 secs, and run it repeatedly with and w/o strict/warnings.

Comment: @zdim Word "performance" was a mistake, let's call it "time to finish task". Running a short-living script numerous times, and response time should be low. Again, we can debate timings, but that is not what the question actually is. It seems word "safety" also was a mistake, let's call it correctness

Comment: @tadman "I don't always turn off safety features, but when I do, it's in production." :D It feels like a (not-so-)secret motto of recent developments in healthcare, food industry, wireless tech, computer systems and other modern events. Good to know this trend is disapproved of on this webpage. I hope this disfavor will get back into other fields of activites where it is currently in decline

Comment: @uxer Is it correct to remove strict and warnings? No. If you are done debugging, they will be silent anyway. Any new issues that arise, from changed input, file structures, software updates, will be revealed only if they are still present. If there are no benefits from removing them, then removing them is incorrect.

Comment: @uxer "_Again, we can debate timings, but that is not what the question actually is._" -- Sure, and in short: cannot disable warnings. Doing that may leave you out in the cold. Not even "ideal" tests (what's that?) can cover every possibility, and the best ones we can actually have for production certainly leave some situations out. (Because you have to, specially those that are extremely unlikely while wouldn't compromise the overall operation.)  And then they may happen, six months after you've turned off warnings.  You'll never even know. Well, but then what does it matter you may say ...

Comment: @uxer ... Well, once we are back in real life then the timings start to matter: you save nothing by leaving out warnings.  And I mean literally _nothing_: Consider two cases: 1) the script takes some time.  Then, timings of successive runs will likely vary more than the compilation of warnings takes 2) the program does very little but needs to be quick -- um, no: if those miliseconds of startup matter then that shouldn't be Perl. It should be a compiled language.

Comment: @uxer Here are a couple of examples.  In a run of a complex program, the NFS  had a glitch (too slow?) and shortly after a file was written it behaved as if the file wasn't there (it was -- I'm not kidding!), so the program took another path, which later made a mess because the original file was there. There were even explicit tests in place and the NFS still tricked me.  How do I even know?  Because no warning was logged which otherwise, in that particular case, would've been there.  This was the only such case in years of daily runs (while there were other puzzling NFS glitches)

Comment: @uxer Another case -- I was asked once precisely for what you now bring up, to trim down a particular program so that it can be called very often, so be _very_ cheap.  (They threw out my advice and offer to then rewrite it in C, duh.)  In short, the best I could do was still a few hundred milliseconds startup (no modules stayed I think). It didn't even cross my mind to touch warnings/strict.

Comment: (I don't mean to monopolize this space so let me know once you've seen these comments and I'll remove them.)

Comment: "_Up till now, replies are mostly evasive ..._"  -- I just noticed this in the update to the question ...  Nothing's been evasive here (??) as multiple people are telling you straight up to not turn off warnings.  There's even a full answer to that effect.  What else do you expect?   (Sure that you _can_ if you tested well but then you still may end up with a surprise, and that's that.)

Comment: @zdim This is a place for discussion, so I would suggest keeping your comments, not removing them. They are yours, however, so do as you like

Comment: Re "*This is a place for discussion,*", Absolutely not. The comments are quite explicitly NOT for discussion. Discussions can be held in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251048).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strict` and `warnings` are developer tools. If you are done developing and everything is clean, you don't need them anymore. Note [what @ikegami has already said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75076787/2766176), though.

In certain environments where all standard error is logged, you have the possibility of some new perl, changed setting, or untested code path emitting warnings. I've had one situation in my career where a formerly clean script started emitting tons of warnings after a perl upgrade. This eventually filled up the disk and brought the service down. That was not fun. If no one is monitoring the warnings, it's pointless to emit them. But, the lesson here is proper monitoring.

I don't think warnings should be enabled in production code because you should have either fixed them or decided to ignore them. Sometime, but rarely, I'll turn off warnings in a very small scope because the fix would make the code harder to read or cause other problems:

```
{
no warnings qw(uninitialized);
....
}
```

But really, I usually just fix warnings and leave warnings enabled. I stopped caring around Perl v5.12 which turns on warnings for free:

```
use v5.12;  # free warnings
```

I care more about specifying the minimal Perl version than removing a `use warnings` or adding a `no warnings` line.

And, with v5.36, I get strictures when I specify that as the minimal version:

```
use v5.36; # free warnings and free strict
```

Finally, your stated penalty is 7ms. If that's the hot path in your code , you're a lucky person. If you are worried about start up time and need that 7ms, there are other things you should be doing to reclaim that start up time.

But, remember that a one time benchmark on a multi-user, multi-process machine, even if you did run it for a couple seconds, is tainted by anything else going on. If you can repeatedly show the 7ms delay through all sorts of loads and situations, then we should believe that. In my own testing of the same thing on my MacBook Pro, I see differences in as much as 30%. I attribute most of that to operating system level stuff happening when I decide to do the test.

Comment: Re "*because you should have either fixed them*", If you fixed them, then there's no cost to having them enabled. You leave them on in case you didn't fix them all.

Comment: Re "*I stopped caring around Perl v5.12 which turns on warnings for free:*", It does not. `use v5.12;` turns on strict, but not warnings. `use v5.36;` is the one that also turns on warnings.

Comment: @ikegami - of course. This is why I shouldn't post when I'm also trying to run out the door.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, neither pragma introduce any performance penalty. They simply set flags which are only checked when the exceptional situations occur, and they are checked whether the pragmas were used or not. So the whole question relies on a false premise.

But to answer your question, both of these pragmas have a run-time effect, so whether removing them with make a difference depends on the thoroughness of your tests. They probably aren't complete, so a difference is possible, even likely.

Comment: "both of these pragmas have a run-time effect", "a difference is possible, even likely" — please clarify whether you meant performance or safety effect or both. My reading is you speak about safety, so effect on safety and difference in safety due to incompleteness of tests. Right? And performance penalty is not introduced. Right? I got 70 seconds difference for 10000 invocations. Please take a look at my updated question. For tests, lets consider an ideal academic scenario of complete coverage. Will there be any difference?

Comment: @uxer A complete test coverage doesn't mean that all possible paths are tried.  There may be circumstances which do not happen during testing -- a file getting removed like I mention in a comment -- which result in an unforseen run.  As for you tests -- they measure compilation, and I don't think that was meant by "performance" in the question.

Comment: Re "*One may or may not care about [...] 70 seconds for 10K invocations*", If you do care, the solution isn't removing `use strict; use warnings;`; it's to use a single invocation to do those 10k requests. Then 70 s becomes 7 ms, all without removing `use strict; use warnings;`. And that's just a tiny tiny tiny fraction of the amount of time you'd save. So like I said, neither pragma introduces any penalty. Your benchmarks do not show otherwise.

Comment: Re "*please clarify whether you meant performance or safety effect or both.*", I very clearly said there's no performance penalty to using them. And "safety" is not what the pragmas do. (That's not even a verb!) The effect of using them is throwing an exception. The alternative would therefore be not throwing an exception.

Comment: "neither pragma introduces any penalty. Your benchmarks do not show otherwise" — they show starup penalties. Word "performance" was my mistake. "I very clearly said there's no performance penalty to using them" — you did. Yet in the 2nd paragraph you said they have "effect" without specifying the nature of the effect, which doesn't help clarity. "Safety" — my mistake on calling it like that. Would the word "correctness" suit? I tend to think you grasped the meaning. If I use wrong wordings, I don't do it intentionally. "not even a verb" — what does it refer to?

Comment: "If you do care, the solution isn't removing `use strict; use warnings;`; it's to use a single invocation to do those 10k requests." — sensible practical suggestion. I'll consider it, TY. Now if you please let's not emphasize timings as the original intent has been to find out about correctness. You said about incompleteness of tests. I appreciate it. If there is something to add, I would be glad to read on it. Whereas if that's all, then that's all

Comment: I meant that "noone" ever has complete tests. And what's relevant here is the most unusual circumstances, which are the most likely to be missing from a test suite.

Comment: Re "*what does it refer to?*", Safety.

Comment: Re "*Would the word "correctness" suit?*", No, *throwing exceptions* is what they do. They don't safety. They don't correctness. Those sentences don't even make sense.

Comment: Re "*they show starup penalties*", No, they don't. At worst, it's an extra 1ms every few minutes. That's less than noise. That's not a penalty.

Comment: @ikegami Word "performance" — no, word "safety" — no, word "correctness" — no. I am apparently bad at picking appropriate terms. Your replies would be more constructive if they offered better names for things discussed. So that we could switch to sentences that do make sense

Comment: @ikegami "That's not even a verb!" — what does it refer to? — "Safety". "They don't safety. They don't correctness". Sorry, but explain to the uninitiated, why there should be a verb?

Comment: @ikegami "At worst, it's an extra 1ms every few minutes. That's less than noise. That's not a penalty" — I wonder how you do those calculations and get 1ms every few minutes

Comment: Re "*Your replies would be more constructive if they offered better names*", I did. Twice. For the third time, "Throws exceptions" is what they do. "Alerts the user of problems" also works.

Comment: Re "*I wonder how you do those calculations and get 1ms every few minutes*", Either you're running the program just occasionally, Or you got continual requests and you write a program that handles multiple requests. Either way, the time to load up the program is inconsequential. We've already covered this to death. Oh, and it's 1 ms, not 7 ms on my desktop.

Comment: Say you do run the program 10k times in a row. You're asking if it's ok to hide errors to save 1*9999 ms when you fixing the prorgam the correct way (loading it just once) would save you 500*9999 or most in just compile time, not to mention database connection times, config parsing times, etc, etc, etc, etc. Making your program run 1000x faster without having to hide errors is way better than making it 1*9999 faster and hiding errors! You've been told this in crystal clear terms, but you keep asking the same answered questions.